# CSS how to animate from the recently applied transform?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am applying a dynamic `transform` to an element when dragging, for example:

### HTML

```
<div style="transform: `translateX(${distance}px) translateY(-${distance / 10}px) rotate(-2deg) scale(0.9)`">
  Drag Me
</div>
```

However when a certain distance has been reached I complete the animation by adding a custom `class`, say `completeAnimation` and the rules go like this:

```
@keyframes animation {
  0% {
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(270px) translateY(-50px) rotate(-15deg) scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(470px) translateY(50px) rotate(-15deg) scale(0.8);
  }
}

.completeAnimation {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: swipeRight;
    animation-fill-mode: animation;
}
```

But obviously, when the class `completeAnimation` is applied to the `class` attribute it jumps back to its default display and directly complete to `100%` in the `animation` css.

Is there a way to start the animation where the last applied `style` left off?

Comment: Beware `.completeAnimation` must be before `@keyframes`

Comment: @LuisP.A. good to know. Any explanation why?

Comment: I think you should save the last transform in a variable using JS.

Comment: @Sam yeah I thought of that but how do I insert it on the `@keyframes` in the css?

Comment: @JohnnyQ Because the css file read up to down (cascading), and  will listen the animation-name first before read the name of the keyframes to execute the animation. (CSS - Cascading Style Sheet)

Comment: @JohnnyQ Maybe the solution is using JS animation instead of CSS keyframes.